# Applications of Products of Random Matrices

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, algorithms, recursive-algorithms, random-matrices

I'm studying the paper ["Matrix concentration for products"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.05437.pdf) and I'm trying to find simple applications of the inequalities for the expected value of the spectral norm of products of random matrices. The exact inequalities are Corollaries 5.4 and 5.6 from the before mentioned paper.

Are there any easy algorithms where such inequalities could be used to show convergence? Are there any other applications I should look at?